# How do I create or specify new color palatte in RColorBrewer using ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, statistics

Sample Data data below referred to as "hello.dat" ,

```
0.9136 -0.2197
0.1145 -0.319
0.2791 -0.2117
0.2155 -0.1370
0.5305 -0.9655
0.7183 -0.1053
0.2973 -0.2086
0.2607 -0.2574
0.5506 -0.3195
0.4192 -0.5939
-0.1025 -0.4676
0.3027 -0.5689
0.2871 -0.5592
0.1335 -0.3442
0.2175 -0.5497
0.3410 -0.5179
0.2992 -0.2266
```

Required packages:

```
require(akima)
require(cluster)
require(colorRamps)
require(dbscan)
require(factoextra)
require(lattice)
require(latticeExtra)
require(MASS)
require(NbClust)
require(RColorBrewer)
```

Silhouette Plot code below,

```
  data <- read.table("hello.dat")

  km.res <- eclust(data, "kmeans",k=4,nstart=1000,graph=FALSE)
  SIL<- silhouette(km.res$cluster,dist(data))


  jpeg(paste(hello,".jpg",sep=""),width=650, height=650, units="px",quality=500,pointsize=12)
  print(fviz_silhouette(km.res, print.summary = FALSE) +
      scale_fill_brewer() +
      scale_color_brewer() +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_text(size=16),
            axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold",size = 14),
            panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank()))
  dev.off()
```

For some reason the code above loads as multiple bars for each 'cluster' instead of a silhouette plot but for the purposes of this question that is okay. I am trying to figure out how to specify color. I figured out how to specify different color palates as saved in RcolorBrewer but I am trying to use an ordered set of 6 primary colors to match the existing cluster representation.
I tried using variations of the code below, but haven't been able to figure it out. I would just like to specify, "blue", "cyan", "green", red", "purple", "orange" as the colors. This specific data set (sample set) has 4 clusters, so I would want the 4 clusters or silhouette representations to be the first 4 colors of the list.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rainbow(n=max(centernum[i]-1))) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours=rainbow(n=max(centernum[i]-1))) +

gradientn(colours=rainbow(n=max(4)))

palette(c("#000000FF", rainbow(n=max(centernum[i]-1))))
```

I have very limited knowledge in coding. I am currently learning R and Linux and until this month didn't know what a "for .." loop was. If you have any questions I'll try to answer as best as I can and please let me know if I left any pertinent information out. Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like this before your graph. You set the colors to be a specific palette from RColorBrewer (or you can create your own, ex: c("blue","cyan",...)
myColors <- brewer.pal(3,"Set1")
names(myColors) <- levels(data$cluster)
colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "Cluster",values = myColors, drop=F)

Comment: So say I do this,    "    mycolors<-c("blue","cyan","green","red","orange","purple")         "          Then what do i enter into the plot code?  scale_fill_brewer(mycolors)
        scale_color_brewer(mycolors) ?

Comment: You will still need to add these lines before your plot: 
names(myColors) <- levels(data$cluster) colScale <- scale_colour_manual(name = "Cluster",values = myColors)

Then, in your plot: You add colScale instead of  scale_color_brewer.